# Trying to click in the message box using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to click on the message box for every new message window that pops up.  However it seems as if the id changes every time.  How do I get this to work for everytime a new message box pops up.

Here is what I tried:

```
passMessage = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('ember-text-area msg-messaging-form__message ember-view')
```

For example:

```
<textarea name="message" spellcheck="true" required="" placeholder="Write a message or attach a file" id="a11y-ember8470" class="ember-text-area msg-messaging-form__message ember-view"></textarea>

<textarea name="message" spellcheck="true" required="" placeholder="Write a message or attach a file" id="a11y-ember8492" class="ember-text-area msg-messaging-form__message ember-view"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a css class name, so you need a dot:

```
passMessage = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.ember-text-area.msg-messaging-form__message.ember-view');
```

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

Comment: I think you do remove spaces. Answer looks right to me.